# Resolve formulas with depending variables using Symfony's ExpressionLanguage

Tags: php, algorithm, symfony, formula, symbolic-math

I'm working on an application that deals with the calculation of roofs and their components.

I'm using Symfony's `ExpressionLanguage` to keep calculations small and readable.

Some formula examples:

- `a` = `atan(Hr / B)`
- `Hr` = `B * tan(a) / 2`
- `R` = `(A - (Hr / tan(90)))`
- `X`= `Hr * R + cos(a)`

Given that every formula knows which variables it needs and `a` or `Hr` have a starting value, what algorithm could be used:

- to resolve all formulas
- throw an exception if not all formulas can be solved with the given variables

I'm writing `PHP`, but I'll accept pseudo code :)

Comment: The first step would be to traverse the [AST](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/expression_language.html#ast-dumping-and-editing) to find the variables that an expression contains.

Comment: @Olivier Indeed, but I got that covered, it's the "resolving" part I'm struggling with...

Comment: For each expression: if every variable has already been evaluated, evaluate the expression. Repeat the loop until either all expressions are evaluated or you get stuck.

Comment: @Olivier Thanks, that's how I ended up doing it. Recursively, by passing the unresolved formulas in again until none are left or until you end up with the same amount of unresolved formulas more than once...